# Manifest merger failed while adding FirebaseUI library and support libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am implementing authentication using google firebase. I am getting this error . If possible please someone suggest solution along with explanation so i can understand.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>    Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.1) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>       is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

Below is my gradle files

1.project module

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

2,module app

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.prerak.final_audio_streamer"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.4.0'//advertisements

    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.4.0'// FirebaseUI Auth only
    compile'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.0'//firebase auth
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'//playservice


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line inside your application tag in the manifest

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
        tools:replace="android:value" />
```

exactly as it shows above. This is not your integer directory it is an Android directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can find in the [official doc:](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#upgrading-dependencies)

> If you would like to use a newer version of one of FirebaseUI's transitive dependencies, such as Firebase, Play services, or the Android support libraries, **you need to add explicit compile declarations in your build.gradle for all of FirebaseUI's dependencies** at the version you want to use.

For Auth you have to add these lines in your `build.gradle`:

```
compile "com.android.support:design:26.1.0"
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile "com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0"
```