# Manifest merger failed, Error while adding firebaseui dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-3.0

I have following dependencies in my app gradle and they work completely fine untill i add firebase ui dependency.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

}
```

This is the ui dependency i want to add.

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.1.0'
```

Build of the project shows following error

```
failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.1.0) 
from [com.android.support:design:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
is also present at [com.android.support:customtabs:25.4.0] 
AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35 value=(25.4.0).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at 
AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
```

Which dependency should i use so that the project builds successfully.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493996/manifest-merger-failed-while-adding-firebaseui-library-and-support-libraries

Comment: Now working... still getting same error

Comment: Modify `com.android.support:customtabs:25.4.0` AS  `implementation("com.android.support:customtabs:25.4.0"){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }` in build.gradle.

Comment: Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at 
AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.