# AndroidManifest: resource integer/google_play_services_version not found

Tags: android, firebase

I have an android Studio (3.2.1) app, with base module and **instantApp** feature, Target API is **28**. Since when I added Firebase, I started having this maniferst merge error in the title, which I solved adding:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

In the **base** app manifest, as mentioned in [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493996/manifest-merger-failed-while-adding-firebaseui-library-and-support-libraries?rq=1) answers on this topic.

App runs OK and firebase stuff works, but integration tests (and instant app) are broken with error:

`resource integer/google_play_services_version (aka it.future.futureandroid.app:integer/google_play_services_version) not found.`

Please notice that I added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in the base app gradle as well, while cloud messaging dependency is only specified inside feature module with:

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'`

while at project-level build.gradle i added:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

I already tried adding `configurations.all` as reported in [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553058/android-manifest-merger-failed-gms-play-services-firebase) questions with no luck. **It seems that manifest merger, only with instantApp and integration tests, cannot resolve that integer/google_play_services_version**

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same problem but couldn't find much information about it. Thanks.